# flink sql kafka connector publish header

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Using flink sql kafka connector, I want to be able to publish the header from the source topic out to the link

my source is defined

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE identity_entitlement_poc /** mode('streaming')*/ (
 `id` string,
 `entitlementAssignments` string,
 `eventTime` AS PROCTIME(),
 `partition` BIGINT METADATA  VIRTUAL ,
 `headers` MAP<STRING, BYTES> METADATA 

)
with (
 'connector' = 'kafka',
 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:29092',
 'properties.group.id' = 'identity-entitlement-local-1',
 'topic-pattern' = 'identity_entitlement_poc',
 'format' = 'json',
 'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
 'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
 'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
 'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'

);
```

Here `headers` is marked as `metadata` but NOT `virtual`.

When i use it in the sink like

```
insert into sink
SELECT
       headers
       id
FROM identity_entitlement_poc
```

my `identity_entitlement_poc` looks like

```
SELECT
       headers
       id
FROM identity_entitlement_poc
```

I get an error saying `header` column not found.